# how to change x axis to find peaks from magnitude spectrum in python

Tags: python, scipy, signals, fft, spectrum

I've loaded an audio file with librosa to plot its magnitude spectrum

```
signal, sr = librosa.load(audio_file, sr=44100)

signal_fft = np.fft.fft(signal)
magnitude = np.abs(signal_fft)
frequency = np.linspace(0, sr, len(magnitude))

plt.plot(frequency[:30000], magnitude[:30000]) # cutting the plot at the Nyquist frequency
plt.xlabel("Frequency (Hz)")
plt.ylabel("Magnitude")
plt.title("Magnitude spectrum")
plt.show()
```

Here is the magnitude spectrum :

[image: magnitude spectrum]

I have then tried to find the peaks of the spectrum with `scipy.signal.find_peaks`

```
peaks, _ = find_peaks(magnitude[:30000], height=350)
plt.plot(magnitude[:30000])
plt.plot(peaks, magnitude[peaks], "x")
plt.show()
```

Then I wanted to know if it is possible to plot the peaks on the frequency scale ?
I'm having troubles to define the x axis because, when it is plotted it is appearing with another scale.

[image: magnitude spectrum with peaks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`'s documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html):

> `x` values are optional and default to `range(len(y))`

As a result, your second plot uses indices for the x-axis instead of frequencies.
To get values in Hz you need the frequency at each of the plotted magnitude, which you fortunately have through your `frequency` variable. You can thus generate your second plot with the same scale as the first with the following:

```
peaks, _ = find_peaks(magnitude[:30000], height=350)
plt.plot(frequency[:30000], magnitude[:30000])
plt.plot(frequency[peaks], magnitude[peaks], "x")
plt.show()
```